# How to display next items from a plist file in a quiz app?

Tags: plist

Just new to xcode. I'm trying to create a quiz app with several questions and answers stored in a plist file. So far the first question and answers are correctly displayed in a labels on the UIView. There is also a next button that displays when the correct answer is given. When the "Next" button is pressed the next question and answers should be loaded into the labels on the UIView.

Any idea what the code for this might be?

Comment: This question is very broad. Stack overflow users can't write your app for you. Please do some research, write some code, and come back if you're having problems.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with hw731 regarding the broadness of this question, however... I recently have been working with plists and I am happy to share an advice based on what I have done.  Typically, what I have found is that something like:

```
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"questions" ofType: @"plist"];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        questionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    }
```

which will turn your plist into an array will allow you to shift your thinking from 'how to get info from a plist' to 'how to iterate through an array'.  You can easily track which question is currently being displayed by it's array index, and then retrieve the next item by incrementing the index.